# Youtube video not playing on mobile

Tags: html, youtube

My embded youtube video won't play on mobile devices (desktop working fine). the videos is trigger when an image which hover it got clicked.i would like to keep it that way just to make it work on mobile.
(i know that it has something to do with the fact that i must emded it)

can you please advice
Thanks a lot!! 
this is the code:

```
a class="thumb-video show-product-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmpEyJJHBC8">
```

Answer (score 1):

in the html, add the unique code of youtube in the last section of url

ex: http://www.youtube.com/v/fmpEyJJHBC8

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public string GetVideo(object MedVideo)
{
    //DataRowView dRView = (DataRowView)imgSRC;

    string v = MedVideo.ToString();
    v = v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf("v=") + 2);
    if (v.Contains("&"))
        v = v.Substring(0, v.LastIndexOf("&"));
    VideoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + v;
    return VideoURL;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aarif! Thanks for replying! should i just set it in the HTML code? pls elaborate for me.. Thanks again